# How would an ISR know what pin cause the interrupt?

Tags: interrupt, microprocessors, isr, msp432

Interrupts can be enabled for a specific pin(s) on a digital I/O port, correct? How would the ISR determine which pin caused the interrupt?

Because the vector table has only one slot for the Port1 ISR. So the same ISR function gets called no matter which input pin on Port1 needs attention unless I'm wrong...

Comment: That is *very* dependent on the MCU you're using.

Comment: I'm using the MSP432, would you happen to know anything about that or how I could find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have suggested in comments this can be MCU dependent, but for ARM(The core behind MSP432)  generally the answer is it doesnt know, it looks for it.
ARM has a `vectored interrupt system`, which means that every source has its own vector of interrupt, so CPU can easily find out which source is triggering thr interrupt. so far so good.
but then it happens that a device can trigger multiple interrupts, like `GPIO` as you said, in this case, CPU knows that which port has triggered interrupt so fires it's `ISR` but then it is `ISR` responsibility to poll device registers to figure out exact interrupt source, there are many of this peripherals with multiple interrupt, timers, DMAs just to name a few.
This is exactly why normally peripherals have an interrupt enable bit, that lets them trigger interrupts, but they also have bit masks that controls what exactly can trigger that interrupt internally,
Also have a look at this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_onxKVQMcZ8J:e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/618474%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ir) for an in action example, specially at their `ISR` that does exactly the same as described above

Comment: @LucasSeran, Welcome, please consider accepting answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In a typical MCU, there are hundreds, or at a stretch even thousands of potential interrupt sources. Depending on the application, only some will be important, and even fewer will be genuinely timing critical.

For a GPIO port, you typically enable only the pins which are interesting to generate an interrupt. If you can arrange only one pin of a port to be generating the interrupt, the job is done, your handler for that *port* can do the work, safely knowing that it will only be called when the right pin is active.

When you care about the cause within a single peripheral, and don't have the luxury of individually vectored handlers, you need to fall back on the 'non vectored' approach, and check the status registers before working out which eventual handler function needs to be called.

Interestingly, you can't work out which pin caused the interrupt - all you can see is which pins are *still* active once you get round to polling the status register. If you care about the phasing between two pulses, you may not be able to achieve this discrimination within a single GPIO unless there is dedicated hardware support. Even multiple exception vectors wouldn't help, unless you can be sure that the first exception is always taken before the second pin could become set.